# How to get ES6 Proxy's target object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy, metaprogramming

I want to extract a target object from Proxy. Is it possible?

```
let foo = new Proxy(bar, {...}) 
let extractedBar = ? // should be plain object, not Proxy
```

I know, I can make my own solution for this. But I wonder is there any standard implementation, so I won't have to edit Proxy's code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance are you really serious? Did you ever read the question? I want to get *target* not *handler*

Comment: The other question is not exactly the same, but the answer there *does* address what you're asking. `ECMAScript provides no way to access the internal [[ProxyHandler]] nor [[ProxyTarget]] slots.`

Comment: @CertainPerformance firstly, I don't think if questions are asking different things they should be marked duplicate, even if they may possibly have common answer. Secondly, I checked that question before, but it's answers didn't satisfy me. Thirdly, I was adding some info to the question when you marked it as a duplicate, and that info indicated, that answers from question you provided are not suitable (you were to fast, I was to slow). What should I do now, ask this question again?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see your last edit. Ok, now I understand. Thanks for pointing to exact piece of answer, I missed it (and hope it is true)

Comment: I'd close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096547/how-to-get-the-target-of-a-javascript-proxy, but it doesn't have an answer yet