# Javascript Proxy how to hide Target and Handler in console and debug

Tags: javascript

How to hide `Target` And `Handler` in console and debug ?

I want to see plain javascript object in console and while debugging.

**Code**

```
    const target = {};
    const proxyobject = new Proxy(target, {});

    proxyobject.name = 'tom';
    proxyobject.address = 'earth';

    console.log(proxyobject);
```

**Output** - In chrome and firefox console are same as below image

[image]

**Note**

1. if i do `JSON.stringify(proxyobject)` it prints json string
2. in some code editors `internal` console it prints json

   2.1 [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vubeqel/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096547/how-to-get-the-target-of-a-javascript-proxy

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const target = {};
    const proxyobject = new Proxy(target, {});

    proxyobject.name = 'tom';
    proxyobject.address = 'earth';

var myData; 
var {name,address,myData={name,address},...others} = proxyobject; 
console.log(myData)
```

We can make use of es6