# Vuex Mutations Proxy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I want to know why when I made a mutation commit the payload is returned as a proxy.

Like you can see here I have this store that contains modules:

[image]

This is the module that I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see this store make a call that brings an array of songs from firebase, and after that commit the mutation to change the state of the array songs.

Well the problem is that the action is dispatched in this component:

[image]

As you can see in the next picture the data comes from firebase but when I check in the console that I made in the mutations, all the state shows up as a proxy object.

[image]

In Vue.js developer tools the state shows as undefined.

[image]

For more info this is the index.js that brings all the modules from the folder modules into the main index.js of the store.

[image]

Comment: Please post code, not paintings of it.

Comment: Can you console.log state value in your component using getter?

Comment: [What does Proxy mean in the console in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64960637/381282)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Proxy mean in the console in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960637/what-does-proxy-mean-in-the-console-in-vue-3)