# computed property shows the array but not the array elements separately

Tags: vue.js

I have a computed property which is---

```
computed: {
      getGrouped() {
        let ColorwithRate = [];
        this.FilteredColor.forEach((c, index) => {
            c.selectedRate = 0;
            console.log(this.getGrouped[index])
            console.log(this.getGrouped[index].selectedColor)
         ColorwithRate.push(c);
        })

        return ColorwithRate;
      }
   },
```

the `console.log(this.getGrouped[index])` shows an array in console.which is---

[image]
But `console.log(this.getGrouped[index].selectedColor` , it shows --

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectedColor')
```

Comment: As you said, `this.getGrouped[index]` is returning an array. Then you have to iterate it to access the properties of an object. Try this : `this.getGrouped[index].forEach(obj => { console.log(obj.selectedRate) })`

Comment: How do I put a value in selectedRate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using Vue3.

[What does Proxy mean in the console in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960637/what-does-proxy-mean-in-the-console-in-vue-3)

Try `console.log(toRaw(this.getGrouped.selectedColor))`.

Comment: showing undefined

Comment: toRaw is not defined --- this is showing