# Nuxt3 useFetch response structure

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use `useFetch` in Nuxt3, however, the responses have a weird format.

Here is the code:

```
<script setup>
const [{ data: organization }, { data: repos }] = await Promise.all([
    useFetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/nuxt'),
    useFetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/nuxt/repos'),
])

console.log('--------organization', organization)
console.log('----------repos', repos)

</script>
```

And here is the response:
[image]

The `_rawValue` and `_value` actually contain the data I need, however, I think this should just be a simple JSON. I'm not sure why it's returning data this way

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960637/what-does-proxy-mean-in-the-console-in-vue-3
Don't panic with the weird object, ES6 Proxy adds reactivity to the object without interfering. You can display data normally in JavaScript: `console.log(organization.value.login);` or inside your template `{{ organization.login }}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ToRaw()"
Example :

```
if(isProxy(organization)) {
    data = toRaw(organization)
    console.log(data)
}
```