# Sort one array based on another array (Proxy from mobx's store) on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

**What i'm trying to do**

I want to go through one array, create another array that represents mapping by index, save it in `Local Storage`, and then when the app first mounts to check if there is a value stored in `Local storage`, and if so then sort the array of data coming from the store (as `Proxy`) So that they are displayed according to the mapping in `LocalStorage`.

Hope the explanation is clear :)

I got the data from store as a `Proxy` like so:

`const chocolates = machineStore?.SubsystemsInfo`

when i console it out, i need to stringify and parse it so i can view it in the console. it look like so:

[image]

When the component mounts, i get the array of **mapped indexes** from LocalStorage,
but the problem now is that i need to render the original array based on it and i can`t because it's a` Proxy `and i can`t get access to the array itself, so i can then sort.

[image]

how can i convert the data to a regular array so i can work with it ?

i already tried  spreading, and parsing so it brings am empty array.

any ideas what do i miss?

Thanx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the target of a JavaScript Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096547/how-to-get-the-target-of-a-javascript-proxy)

Comment: Maybe you can make small repro on https://codesandbox.io? It's not very clear what is the problem