# How to check if we have already created proxy on Object using ObservableSlim?

Tags: javascript, object, es6-proxy

I am using `ObservableSlim` to create proxy.

> The create method of ObservableSlip will return a standard ES6 Proxy.

I have created a proxy on object like this:

```js
const proxy = ObservableSlim.create(model, null, (changes) => {});
```

**Problem:**

How will i know that `proxy` is **ES6 Proxy**?

Comment: Regarding your problem specifically: https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim#proxy-check

Comment: @georg I think it was not duplicated because of ObservableSlim.

Comment: You think there's anything more to say? Should I reopen?

Comment: Yes you can reopen and add your comment as answer.

Comment: fair enough, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372611/how-to-test-if-an-object-is-a-proxy), this is impossible in the general case (without dirty hacks at least), because `Proxy` objects are by design transparent and mimic their targets on every system call.

However, library authors realize that that might be inconvenient sometimes and provide hooks in their Proxy objects so that the user can detect them. For the library in question, the returned Proxy exposes the property [`__isProxy`](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim#proxy-check) for this exact purpose.

Comment: I didn't realize they had this functionality in their library. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't from the codes perspective as Proxies are completely transparent.

The only one that knows that it is a Proxy is the console:

```
 console.log(proxy);
```