# Chrome Devtools formatter for javascript proxy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I've recently started using proxies in one of my projects.  The one downside of this has been that when inspecting the object in a debugger, it's now wrapped by the proxy [javascript proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

[image]

Intead of seeing `[[Handler]],[[Target]],[[isRevoked]]` I would prefer to just see the object referenced by `[[Target]]`.

It's a minor inconvenience but I think that it could be solved with a [Chrome Devtools custom formatter](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/19/custom-chrome-devtools-object-formatters.html).

Seems like this would be fairly common, but I can't find any existing formatters.  Just wanted to double check that there wasn't already one out there before I go down the road of writing my own.

Comment: If you write a formatter, please open an issue on https://github.com/google/webfundamentals and I'll create a doc of community-developed formatters.

Comment: Oh gosh I would *never* want this!!! Loosing the intent of a Proxy in the dev output would give me an aneurysm! I mean if it were really bad fine add a `toString` to the Proxy object. But seriously I don't like the idea of the dev tools hiding things from me even if it means one extra triangle click.

Comment: @Sukima it makes sense for tooling that is adding proxy abstraction layers (EX: mobx).  As a consumer of that library, you don't want to have to be concerned with what it is doing behind the scenes.  

I'm not suggesting that you do this for all proxies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it turns out this is quite difficult to achieve.  The first problem is that it's [impossible to identify a Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372611/how-to-test-if-an-object-is-a-proxy) without:

[A:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198132/800619) Adding a custom symbol to your proxy implementation (if you control the Proxy init code)

[B:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463589/800619) Overriding the `window.Proxy` prototype and using a Weakset to basically track every proxy init

On top of that, there is no way to access to original `[[Target]]` object.  However, running `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` does seems to work well for just `console.log` purposes.

Assuming you don't have control to modify the Proxy handler, this is what your solution would look like:

```
// track all proxies in weakset (allows GC)
const proxy_set = new WeakSet();
window.Proxy = new Proxy(Proxy, {
      construct(target, args) {
        const proxy = new target(args[0], args[1]);
        proxy_set.add(proxy);
        return proxy;
      },
});

window.devtoolsFormatters = [{
  header(obj: any) {
    try {
      if (!proxy_set.has(obj)) {
        return null;
      }
      return ['object', {object: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))}]; //hack... but seems to work
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
},
  hasBody() {
      return false;
  },
}];
```

Comment: If you're using Mobx, you can use `mobx.toJS(obj)` instead of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: Also thank you for the answer, it was immensely helpful

Comment: Just a reminder for others, you do have to enable this in the devtools settings. See: https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/19/custom-chrome-devtools-object-formatters.html